# Error in Pygame "Hello World" program Mac OS 10.8

Tags: python, sdl, pygame

I am running Pygame in Mountain Lion. I think it is all installed correctly as I can import the module without any errors.

When I try and run a very simple program I get an exception. Here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello World!")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Here is the exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1000) creating CGSWindow on line 259'

First throw call stack:

(
0   CoreFoundation 0x00007fff89699b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198

1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff83b433f0 objc_exception_throw + 43

2   CoreFoundation 0x00007fff896998dc +[NSException raise:format:] + 204

3   AppKit 0x00007fff85492b49 _NSCreateWindowWithOpaqueShape2 + 655

4   AppKit 0x00007fff85491340 -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 2002

5   AppKit 0x00007fff8544fd82 -[NSWindow _commonInitFrame:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 1763

6   AppKit 0x00007fff8544eecf -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1568

7   AppKit 0x00007fff8544e89f -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 45

8   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib 0x00000001043cbaf9 -[SDL_QuartzWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 279

9   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib 0x00000001043c951b QZ_SetVideoMode + 1409

10  libSDL-1.2.0.dylib 0x00000001043c0809 SDL_SetVideoMode + 907

11  display.so 0x000000010444330f set_mode + 271

12  Python 0x00000001040be754 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7873

13  Python 0x00000001040bc769 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638

14  Python 0x00000001040bc0fd PyEval_EvalCode + 54

15  Python 0x00000001040dae88 run_mod + 53

16  Python 0x00000001040daf2f PyRun_FileExFlags + 137

17  Python 0x00000001040daa7d PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 718

18  Python 0x00000001040eb593 Py_Main + 3039

19  libdyld.dylib  0x00007fff862497e1 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I think it's the pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300)) that is causing it. My Googling tells me it's something graphical, possibly to do with SDL, but I don't understand enough to be able to fix it.

Comment: Go trough the code with a debugger and look where it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the SDL video driver is not initialized properly. First make sure `pygame.init()` returns `(6,0)`. This should tell you if everything is initialized properly. If not, you can check what video driver it is using `pygame.display.get_driver()`. If it is not using the right driver for your machine, you can change it by setting the environment variable `os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER']=` to one of the following `x11, dga, fbcon, directfb, ggi, vgl, svgalib, aalib` (from [pygame documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html)), depending on the drivers available.

Have a look at pygame FAQ on [how to change the video driver](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How%20do%20I%20set%20the%20video%20driver%20Pygame%20uses?).