# PYGAME: ERROR: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1000) creating CGSWindow on line 259

Tags: python, pygame, sdl

This is my first post on stack overflow. I have been trying to run a pygame code on my MAC Mountain Lion, and after installing pygame successfully when I try to `set_mode` for the display using the command

```py
pygame.display.set_mode([700,400])
```

I get the following error

```
2013-12-19 18:31:12.299 Python[25975:f0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error (1000) creating CGSWindow on line 259'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86c7bb06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8aab93f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff86c7b8dc +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff88231b49 _NSCreateWindowWithOpaqueShape2 + 655
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff88230340 -[NSWindow _commonAwake] + 2002
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff881eed82 -[NSWindow _commonInitFrame:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 1763
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff881edecf -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1568
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff881ed89f -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 45
    8   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib                  0x000000010054b9cd -[SDL_QuartzWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 265
    9   libSDL-1.2.0.dylib                  0x000000010054943d QZ_SetVideoMode + 1423
    10  libSDL-1.2.0.dylib                  0x000000010054069c SDL_SetVideoMode + 936
    11  display.so                          0x00000001005c330f set_mode + 271
    12  Python                              0x00000001000c277d PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 21405
    13  Python                              0x00000001000c4786 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2118
    14  Python                              0x00000001000c48a6 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
    15  Python                              0x00000001000e912e PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
    16  Python                              0x00000001000e93ca PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458
    17  Python                              0x000000010010044d Py_Main + 3101
    18  Python                              0x0000000100000f14 Python + 3860
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
[Finished in 1.9s with exit code -6]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/krutirag/Documents/Coding/Python/GameDev/Main.py"]
[dir: /Users/krutirag/Documents/Coding/Python/GameDev]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I installed both python and pygame using brew. I searched extensively for solutions but did not get anything useful for this error. Appreciate any suggestion or help with this. (I found a similar question in stackOverflow , but I could not comment on that since I am new to the forum and do not have the points for it)

Comment: what is the other question? Also, what version of Python are you using and what version of Pygame?

Comment: also, how are you running the program? From a command line, IDE, IDLE?

Comment: Thanks for the response! The other similar question I found in stackflow is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125292/error-in-pygame-hello-world-program-mac-os-10-8?rq=1). I am using commandline, and sublime text. Python version is 2.7.6.

Comment: I am voting to close this question due to the lack of debugging details. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).